# Java: setText() and threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jlabel, settext

I am a beginner in java and unfortunately I was stuck on this problem. In code:

NewJFrame.java :

> ```
> public class NewJFrame extends JFrame {
>
>     public void showText() {
>         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
>             public void run() {
>                 jLabel1.setText("in show()"); //it does not work
>                 System.out.println("in show()"); //it works
>             }
>         });
>     }
>
>     public NewJFrame() {
>         initComponents();
>         jLabel1.setText("start"); //it works
>     }
>
>     public static void main(String args[]) {
>         Timer timer = new Timer();
>         timer.schedule(new NewClass(), 1000, 2000);
>
>         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
>             public void run() {
>                 new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
>             }
>         });
>     }
>     private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
> }
> ```

NewClass.java :

```
package newpackage;

import java.util.TimerTask;

class NewClass extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("in NewClass.run()"); //it works
        new NewJFrame().showText();
    }
}
```

I have a problem with the fact that the setText does not set jLabel1 when is called from timer thread. I tried to solve the problem using invokeLater(), but still does not work.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Using `java.util.TimerTask` in this case will violate Swing single `Thread` rule - You must never create or modify and UI component from outside the EDT.  This is way you you are been recommended to use `java.swing.Timer`

Comment: A lot of the answer to this might lie in the missing code to `initComponents();`.  Like I mentioned earlier, 'for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)'.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a new instance of `NewJFrame` in `NewClass` which never gets displayed:

```
new NewJFrame().showText();
```

You would need to pass the visible instance to `NewClass` for it to be updated.

However, better to use `javax.swing.Timer` rather than `java.util.Timer` to interact with Swing components. From [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html):

> In general, we recommend using Swing timers rather than general-purpose timers for GUI-related tasks because Swing timers all share the same, pre-existing timer thread and the GUI-related task automatically executes on the event-dispatch thread.

Also See: [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

The `JLabel` is never added to any container.  Why would it appear?

As general advice, don't extend frame, simply keep a reference and as mentioned by @Reimeus, use a Swing `Timer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `repaint()` right after you set the text.

After changing the look of something on screen, you must always repaint the frame.

```
jLabel1.setText("in show()");    //it does not work
repaint();                       //now it works
System.out.println("in show()"); //it works
```

Comment: I believe `JLabel#setText()` does not require `repaint()`. Let's wait for Swing geeks for confirmation :)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: The text is a bound property; if `repaint()` is required, @Andrew's comment was right.